# py2app worked with Homebrew, now it builds w/ module missing

Tags: macos, python-2.7, homebrew, py2app

I have a new MacBook w/ Yosemite. In an attempt to get OSC, Zeroconf, PySide and Kivy working, I installed too much via Homebrew.  I've successfully (?) undone most of the damage, I think, and have installed all the Python modules so that Apple's Python finds everything... from the terminal window.

However, now my code runs from the console, correctly importing a custom pythonosc module installed with "sudo python setup.py install", but when I package it with py2app it can no longer find pythonosc. (It found it previously with Python et al installed a la Homebrew.)

Answer (score 0):

You say you've "installed too much via Homebrew" and need "Apple's Python to find everything"

> After installing Python modules into Homebrew's site-packages, you can make them importable from outside.

First make a directory here (assuming 2.7):
`mkdir -p ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`
Then put a path file in it:
`echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("'$(brew --prefix)'/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth`